# Facebook search implementation in android

Tags: android, facebook

I need to search facebook user by using his name or mail-id just like how it works in facebook search box. Any API's available for that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will get a bunch of options for searching at this link here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/. On this page, you will need to scroll down a bit till you find the **Searching** heading.

I am personally, not aware of any provision to search using the email address.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look to the facebook developer documents talking  about android and and the example provide in the SDK first

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/

It will help you to recognize how to use the facebook-android-sdk

Here's are the code

```
 Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("q", "Your Name");
    params.putString("type", "user");//fix
String resp = fb.request("search", params, "GET");//call the request function of android sdk 2.X, ensure you have well setup the library and logged
```